# Bean bundle type

Tags: 7, entities, blocks

I want to use hook_field_enable() to enable required fields when I enable my bean. In order to do so I need to know the bundle type in order to create the instance

```
$instance = array(
      'field_name' => 'name of my field',
      'entity_type' => '?',
      'label' => t('Bean Label'),
      'bundle' => '?',
      'required' => FALSE,
      'settings' => array(),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
      ),
    );
```

what should I replace with the ? in order for the

```
field_create_instance($instance);
```

to work?

Update
I created the bean, it's called

```
function list_bean_bean_types() {
  $plugins = array();
  $plugin_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'list_bean') . '/plugins';
  $plugins['list_bean'] = array(
    'label' => t('List Bean'),
    'description' => 'bla bla bla',
    'handler' => array(
      'class' => 'ListBean',
      'parent' => 'bean',
    ),
    'path' => $plugin_path,
    'file' => 'ListBean.class.inc',
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

compared to attaching a field to a node

```
$instance = array(
      'field_name' => kittens,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'label' => t('Hello Kitty'),
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'required' => FALSE,
      'settings' => array(),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
      ),
    );
```

Comment: `bean_get_types()` will get you a list of all bundles that currently exist

Comment: Thanks for the comment Clive, but I still need to know what to add to bundle?

Comment: One of the values you get back in the array from `bean_get_types()`...it'll depend on what bean types you have set up (there may even be a default one but running that function will tell you for sure)

Comment: I created the bean, just a dummy, but does it mean list_bean is my bundle?